# Order comments text area in checkout

Tags: 8, commerce

I need a order comments text area in checkout. How can I do this?
I'm using Drupal Commerce 2.

Comment: You want to ADD comments in the order area of checkout ?

Comment: For future reference, to avoid downvotes and to make it easier for others to help, include what you've tried and the research you've done in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [commerce_checkout_order_fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_order_fields) will allow you to add extra fields in your checkout process

From the module page

> This can be used to collect additional data during the checkout, for
>   example:
>   - Order comments
>   - Shipping notes
>   - ..